# How to receive emails in postfix/dovecot that authenticate with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, postfix-mta, dovecot

I want to receive emails in postfix/dovecot but the user is on the Active directory.

So far I have setup 3 servers. 1 application server, 1 mailserver and 1 AD server.
So I will use the application server to send notification using mailserver. And to send email, it will need to authenticate to AD server. I hope it makes sense.

Dovecot-ldap.conf:

```
hosts = 1.2.3.4
base = dc=domain.com,dc=com
ldap_version = 3
dn = domain\administrator
dnpass = 'password'
auth_bind = yes
auth_bind_userdn = %u

user_attrs = =home=/home/vmail/%u@domain.com,=uid=1001,=gid=1001
```

10-mail.comf

```
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/domain.com/%u/Maildir
```

I have a valid domain and have set up MX record.
I am able to send email, but I can't receive emails. It just seems like the AD user does not exist in the mailserver.

```
to=<user_2@domain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.07, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "user_2")
```

I don't have any clue from here, so any suggestion would be appreciate.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up Postfix and dovecot to use for doain.
And I just set it up as experimental domain and setup,
So for buisnss propose, you have to take care about som security issues that I've set (Such like cleartext admin's password\ use root accont and so on).

This is my setup:

Dovecot.cont:

```
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp

dict {
}

service lmtp {

    unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
        group = postfix
        mode = 0600
        user = postfix
    }
}

!include conf.d/*.conf

!include_try local.conf
```

dovecot-ldap.conf + dovecot-ldap.conf.ext:

```
hosts = <Domain-Controller IP>:3268
dn = cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=<domainName>,dc=local
dnpass = Administrator password
base = ou=domain-users,dc=somainName,dc=local
ldap_version = 3
blocking = yes

auth_bind_userdn = %u
auth_bind = yes

pass_attrs = \
=user=%{ldap:mailRoutingAddress},\
=password=%{ldap:userPassword}


pass_filter = (mailRoutingAddress=%n)
user_filter = (&(mail=%u)(objectClass=person)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))

iterate_attrs = mailRoutingAddress=user
iterate_filter = (objectClass=smiMessageRecipient)
```

10-auth.conf:

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no

auth_debug = yes
listen = *
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%u/Maildir
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
passdb {
  args = username_format = %n
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf
  driver = ldap
}
protocols = imap pop3
userdb {
  args = username_format = %n
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf
  driver = ldap
}

!include auth-system.conf.ext
!include auth-ldap.conf.ext
```

10-mail.conf:

```
    mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/user/%n/Maildir
    mail_privileged_group = mail

    mail_uid = 1003
    mail_gid = 1003

    mail_uid = 1002
    mail_gid = 1002
    
    mail_uid = 1000
    mail_gid = 1000

    mail_uid = 1001
    mail_gid = 1001

namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
}

first_valid_uid = 1

protocol !indexer-worker {
}

mbox_write_locks = fcntl
```

15-lda.conf:

```
protocol lda {
}
```

20-imap.conf:

```
protocol imap {

}
```

20-lmtp.conf:

```
protocol lmtp {
  postmaster_address = postmaster@domainname   # required
  mail_plugins = quota sieve
}
```

auth-checkpassword.conf.ext:

```
passdb {
  args = username_format = %n
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf
  driver = ldap
}
protocols = imap pop3
userdb {
  args = username_format = %n
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf
  driver = ldap
}
```

auth-ldap.conf:

```
passdb {
  args = username_format = %n
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf
  driver = ldap
}

userdb {
  args = username_format = %n
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf
  driver = ldap
}
```

10-master.conf:

```
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
  }
}

service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
  }
}

service lmtp {
  unix_listener lmtp {
  }
}

service imap {
}

service pop3 {
}

service auth {
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
    mode=0777
  }

  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0777
  }

}

service auth-worker {
  user = $default_internal_user
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0777
    user = postfix
  }
}

service dict {
  unix_listener dict {
  }
}
```

From postfix:
main.cf:

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix

command_directory = /usr/sbin

daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix

data_directory = /var/lib/postfix

mail_owner = postfix


myhostname = emailsrv.morsound.local

mydomain = morsound.local

myorigin = $mydomain


inet_interfaces = all

inet_protocols = ipv4


mydestination = myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost


unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550


mynetworks = <SUBNET>/24, 127.0.0.0/8


alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases

alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

home_mailbox = /var/mail/user/%n
mail_spool_directory = /home/mail/%u/Maildir




mailbox_transport = dovecot

virtual_transport = dovecot

debug_peer_level = 2

virtual_mailbox_domains = morsound.local


debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5


sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix

newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix

mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix

setgid_group = postdrop

html_directory = no


smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man

sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES

mailbox_command = /usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT"
```

master.cf:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=test1:test1 argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

I've added each user manually to server (adduser).
Set mail directory (mkdir /var/spool/mail/user/) and set permission manually.

Hope that will help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).